# Finding the width of an element when using React?

Tags: css, reactjs

At which point in a React components life cycle can I get the components css properties which are set in a css file?

I've tried it in the render method and the componentDidMount method and neither assigned the css properties to the component.

```
export default class HomeArtist extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);   
}
componentDidMount(){
    let ImageStore = document.getElementsByClassName('home-artist-display');
    console.log("ComponentDidMount: ", ImageStore);
}
render(){
    var ImageStyle = {
        backgroundImage: "url("+this.props.info.image+")"
    };
    return (
        <div className="home-artist-display" style={ImageStyle}>
            <Link to={"artist/" + this.props.info.id}>
                <h3 className="home-artist-name">{this.props.info.name}</h3>
            </Link>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Could you please add some example-code to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a React library that exposes a size object (with width and height props) to components.

For your use case you could use it like so:

```
import SizeMe from 'react-sizeme';  // import me!   

class HomeArtist extends React.Component {
  ...
  render(){
      // Size gets passed in as props!
      const { width, height } = this.props.size;

      var ImageStyle = {
          backgroundImage: "url("+this.props.info.image+")"
      };
      return (
          <div className="home-artist-display" style={ImageStyle}>
              <Link to={"artist/" + this.props.info.id}>
                  <h3 className="home-artist-name">{this.props.info.name}</h3>
              </Link>
          </div>
      )
  }
}

// wrap your component export!
export default SizeMe()(HomeArtist);
```

--

You can find out full details at https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-sizeme